# in casperjs click input element and display Error: cannot access member `evaluate' of deleted QObject

Tags: javascript, phantomjs, casperjs

I scraping website with casperjs.
When click a element, display Error: cannot access member `evaluate' of deleted QObject.
Then proceeded not.

Does anyone know what this means? What can I do to stop this happening?

Here is my code to click the button

```
casper.start(url, function(){
  var cookies = JSON.stringify(phantom.cookies)
  fs.write(cookiePath, cookies, 644)
  casper.wait(2000)
})

//click
casper.waitForSelector(clickElem, function(){
  casper.evaluate(click, clickElem)
  casper.wait(3000)
  })

//////////// error in here ↓
casper.then(function(){
  var hrefs = casper.evaluate(getValues, options.block.hrefpath, 'href')
})

function click(elem){
  // find element to send click to
  var element = document.querySelector(elem)
  // create a mouse click event
  var event = document.createEvent( 'MouseEvents' )
  event.initMouseEvent( 'click', true, true, window, 1, 0, 0 )
  // send click to element
  element.dispatchEvent( event )
}

function getValues(elem, attr) {
  var doms = document.querySelectorAll(elem)
  return Array.prototype.map.call(doms, function(e) {
    if(attr) return e.getAttribute(attr)
    else return e.textContent
  })
}
```

Comment: If the error is really appearing there, then it can only mean that PhantomJS has some kind of bug. Which PhantomJS version do you use? Have you tried upgrading or downgrading?

Comment: I use phantomjs version 1.9.7 and casperjs version 1.1.0-beta3
now i upgrading to version 2.0.0 and 1.0.4
try version 2.0.0 and 1.1.0-beta3, version 1.9.8 and 1.1.0-beta3, 1.9.8 and 1.0.4
... same error happen ...
Error: cannot access member `evaluate' of deleted QObject                       
  /Users/scrape:1049 in injectClientUtils
  /Users/scrape:605 in evaluate
  /Users/scrape:805 in getCurrentUrl
  /Users/scrape:1318 in runStep
  /Users/scrape:332 in checkStep